# How do I select the 1st n characters or through the fist "<"?

Tags: php, regex

I am auto-generating an incipit (first bit of a string as an intro) using regex. The incipit is used in a Twig template. The original string can include html. If my incipit ends within html tags, it breaks the Twig template. I want to get the first 260 characters **OR** all characters from the beginning of the string to the first `<`, whichever is **fewer characters**.

This works for first 260 characters:

```
if (preg_match('/^.{1,260}\b/s', $body, $match)) {
    $incipit=$match[0]; 
    if (strlen($body >= 260)) {
        $incipit .= "&hellip;"; //adding ellipsis only if body is truncated 
    } 
}
```

I tried adding an or within my regex.

```
preg_match('/^.{1,260}\b|[^>]/s', $body, $match))
```

But, that does not work the `|` seems to be ignored.

Comment: Maybe `\A[\s\S]+?(?:[\s\S]{259}|<)`? It's not clear if one has priority over the other. If not a simple `\A[^<]{1,260}` works.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I did attempt to be as clear as possible. I learned from both of you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first. You don't need word boundary i.e. `\b`.

**OR** condition won't be useful here and can create a conflict if both conditions are satisfied (i.e. `<` is also present and the characters is less than 260).

You can use this regex instead

```
^[^<]{1,260}
```

[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/LmXFCW/3)

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
[^<] #Negated character class. Match anything other than <
{1,260} # Repeat it between 1 to 260 chaarcters
```

This regex will work according to whichever condition satisfies first.

Comment: A word-boundary is needed if you want to avoid trailing non-significant characters or ugly things (like a dot followed by an horizontal ellipsis), and more particularly a right word-boundary: `^[^<]{1,260}[[:>:]]`.

Comment: Also note that these patterns become wrong if the string contains multibyte characters and/or combining characters.